# Передача данных из Activity в Thread

Tags: android, многопоточность, activity

Как передать данные из Thread в Activity, я, вроде, разобрался:
  `В`Activity` определить хендлер:

```
public Handler myHandler = new Handler() {
   @Override
   public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      //здесь что-нибудь делаем
   }
};
```

который будет вызываться из потока следующим образом:

```
myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

Вопрос: а как правильно передавать данные из  Activity в Thread?

Comment: @selya, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите, тут слово `Activity` лучше заменить на `MainThread (UI Thread`). То есть у Вас есть два потока, один главный, другой порожденный. 
Если Вам нужно передать данные в потом перед стартом( метод `start` ), то тут все очень просто, Вы можете создать собственный класс и наследоваться от Thread.Вот маленький пример

```
  // Somewhere in activity 
    String someText = "Hello World!";
    Thread myThread = new CustomThread(someText);
    public class CustomThread
    {   
    private passedString;
    public CustomThread(String inputText) {
          this.passedString = inputText;
      }
            @Override
            public void run() {  
             System.out.println(this.passedString);
        //Do some stuff
            } 
    }
```

Если же Вы хотите передавать данные в уже запущенный работающий поток можно поступить несколькими способами. 
Можно сделать переменную булевую в классе потока и в цикле, например, пока она не истинна, то делать, что-то, как только истинна, то прочитать глобальную статическую переменную общую или же сделать метод, который устанавливает переменную объекта кастомного потока, при установлении флага будет перечитывать новое значение.Если надо- напишите, я покажу пример.

Или же способ покрасивее это использовать блокирующую очередь.. Тут паттерн многопоточного программирования `Consumer &&  Producer` используется. Вот пример

```
final BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println(queue.take());

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             // Handle Error
                System.err.println("Error:" + e);
            }
        }
    }
});

myThread.start();
queue.offer("Hello World");
}
```

Я честно говоря точно не уверен, что это все возможные способы, может кто-то еще знает.